# provisioning profile -request timed out Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5, provisioning-profile

I added a new app to my Xcode and trying to update my provisioning profiles under Window-Organizer-Library,after giving apple developer credits, it is showing the error -the request timed out.It worked fine before for the 2 apps and I just have one account in the TEAMS, I checked Code signing in the new app and it is fine.Does the apple developer site still down??
Please help me on finding the issue.Any help would be appreciated.

[image: When I am trying to add manually it showing the option menu with the apps before ... I cant add the APP ID manually as before ..is there anything I am missing here]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the status site says that automatic Xcode configuration is not working yet. https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/

You can still use the manual way of generating and downloading certificates from the dev portal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.To add manually I have a problem,I added a picture above, I cant add App Id manually and it is not showing my new app in the option,is there anything I am doing wrong

Comment: xcode configuration is back .I added my app and it working great :)