# I purchased iOS developer license for iPhone and I am not able to add Profile to my iPhone 5. Request Timed Out

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

When I connected my iPhone5 to my Mac after purchasing developer license, xCode recognized it and gave a button for 'Use iPhone for development'. I clicked on it but entered wrong password by mistake when it asked. But after that I didn't saw that button again.

I tried adding a profile by clicking on 'Add Profile + ' button, it always take some time and finally gives 'Request Timed Out' message. This has been happening from the last week.

Please advise how can I fix it.

Comment: I think this is still connected to the problems the IOS Dev center had the last couple of weeks. The Development center got hacked..

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17979102/1144632

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Server is down, but:

- Create profile in portal
- Download profile from portal
- open Xcode
- switch to device organizer
- click profiles (not sure about the name though)
- import profile

Done.